# css conditioning style applying react

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I have a reusable component that receives one of the 2 states according to the use case.
Im trying to apply css styles depending which state was provided. Why this does not work and apply only styles from the "status" state? It just ignore that "isVerified" state condition. And im using chakra ui.

```js
type Props = {
  isVerified?: boolean;
  status?: "active" | "inactive" | undefined;
};


 export const TestIcon = ({
  status,
  isVerified,
}: Props): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Icon
      backgroundColor={
        (status === "active" ? "green.50" : "dark.50") ||
        (isVerified ? "dark.800" : "dark.50")
      }
      borderRadius="full"
      boxSize="illustrationSize"
      fill={
        (status === "active" ? "green.500" : "dark.200") ||
        (isVerified ? "base.white" : "dark.200")
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: How is Icon recieving these properties? Also, what is green.50? that is not a style. Are you using something like tailwind? in which case make sure its configured.

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, its chakra ui and its fully configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to `status === "active" ? "green.50" : "dark.50"`
it will always go to the false it the status is argument is false
I think it's should be like

```
status === "active" ? "green.50" : isVerified ? "dark.800" :"dark.50"
```

or do this as method with if else with what is your top priority
like:

```
if(status === "active") return "green.50";
if(isVerified) return "dark.800";
return  "dark.50"
```

Comment: Ok, this worked: `status === "active" ? "green.50" : isVerified ? "dark.800" :"dark.50"` but without that `"dark.50"` at the end in ur suggestion

Comment: @Adrian
I suggest writing a function  with if as the second one I wrote because when ternary operator have elseif it can become more messy and with a function you make it clearer